# R Repeat a case_when for multiple (similar) variables (eq. var1, var2, var3)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using case_when (dplyr) in a multiple variable dataframe to get the first requested endpoint for each patient.
Endpoint1:Endpoint7 is a data-table in which possible endpoints are named (i.e. hospital visit, sick, dead etc.). For each patient, these are chronological, thus Endpoint1 always would've happened before Endpoint2. 'deathlist' is a list of the specific outcomes that I want to get.
The code below works well.

**I want to check whether it's possible to shorten the following code so that Endpoint1:Endpoint7 are applied in a loop.** However, I've failed to do so. Is anyone capable of doing so? I'm using similar codes multiple times ('deathlist' and the replacing variable change); thus if Endpoint1 is 'infectious', the corresponding DateEndpoint1 will be given.

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
n <- 6
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
                  Endpoint1= c('None', 'Sick', 'Went to hospital', 'Sick', 'Dead - Infectious', 'None'),
                  Endpoint2= c('Sick', 'Went to hospital', 'Dead - Vascular', 'Sick', 'None', 'None'),
                  Endpoint3= c('None', 'Sick', 'None', 'Went to hospital', 'None', 'None'),
                  Endpoint4= c('None', 'Sick', 'Went to hospital', 'Sick', 'None', 'None')
                  )

 dat
  id         Endpoint1        Endpoint2        Endpoint3        Endpoint4
1  1              None             Sick             None             None
2  2              Sick Went to hospital             Sick             Sick
3  3  Went to hospital  Dead - Vascular             None Went to hospital
4  4              Sick             Sick Went to hospital             Sick
5  5 Dead - infectious             None             None             None
6  6              None             None             None             None

intlist <- c('Sick', 'Went to Hospital')

dat %<>% 
        mutate(
          newname = case_when(
            str_detect(Endpoint1, paste(intlist, collapse = "|")) ~ as.character(Endpoint1), 
            str_detect(Endpoint2, paste(intlist, collapse = "|")) ~ as.character(Endpoint2), 
            str_detect(Endpoint3, paste(intlist, collapse = "|")) ~ as.character(Endpoint3), 
            str_detect(Endpoint4, paste(intlist, collapse = "|")) ~ as.character(Endpoint4),  
            TRUE ~ 'None'
          )
        )
```

My goal is to obtain something like:

```
at %<>% 
    mutate(
      newname = case_when(sapply(Endpoint1:Endpoint7, function(x)
        str_detect(x, paste(intlist, collapse = "|")) ~   as.character(x)
        TRUE ~ 'None'
      )
    )
```

I.e. I'd like to replace the repeating of these easy str_detect(endpoint1....) lines for all Endpoints1-7.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `rowwise()` and `c_across()`

```
dataframe.example %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    WhichEndpoint = str_subset(
      c_across(starts_with("Endpoint")),
      pattern = paste(deathlist , collapse = "|")
      )[1]
  ) %>%
  mutate(WhichEndpoint = if_else(is.na(WhichEndpoint),"None",WhichEndpoint))
```

This converts your `dataframe.example` into a rowwise data.frame, which basically means our functions act solely on individual rows, and not on the data.frame as a whole. This is similar to `group_by_all()`, but is more specific and allows for `c_across()`. `c_across()` creates "horizontal" vectors in this new rowwise data.frame. So in this example, we are turning all the variables that `starts_with("Endpoint")` into a vector in each row. Since this is now a vector, we can apply vector-based functions to it, such as `str_subset()`. `str_subset()` extracts all elements in a vector which matches the given pattern.

So:

```
str_subset(c_across(starts_with("Endpoint")),pattern = paste(deathlist , collapse = "|"))
```

will return a vector for each row, with just the places where an entry matches the pattern, i.e. is in your `deathlist` variable. Then, extract the first element using `[1]` to get the first match. If no matches are found, this will return `NA`, which can then be replaced by `"None"`.

An alternative that does not use regex matching (which may cause a problem if your `deathlist` variable has certain characters, such as `\` ,`{`, or `[`) can be to use `keep()` and `first()` from `purrr` (also in `tidyverse`)

```
dataframe.example %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    WhichEndpoint = first(keep(
      c_across(starts_with("Endpoint")),
      ~. %in% deathlist
    ))
  )
```

This time, we still use the `rowwise()` and `c_across()` function, but rather than matching our horizontal vector with a regex, we check it against a lambda function: `~. %in% deathlist`. This runs the call `. %in% deathlist` on the horizontal vector that we are passing into `keep()`, and it will keep any element which returns `TRUE` (i.e. those elements that are in the `deathlist` variable. We can the use `first()` rather than `[1]` to grab just the first element of this list, I feel like this is a little cleaner than adding a `[1]` to the end.

Comment: Thanks alot. I've tried the first code which uses regex and it has the same output as my own code. However, the second (tidyverse) code doesnt give the same output. This is probably due to the fact that all elements in deathlist are not perse equal to whats in Endpoint. For Example, I put the word 'hospital' in deathlist to get 'Admitted to hospital', '' Died in hospital' etc. when I use deathlist (as a pattern).

Comment: Ahh, that's fair. Using the `~. %in% deathlist` will check for exact matches, and not if the string contains it. The regex way works perfectly fine anyway. As I said, just be wary of [special characters](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html) in your `deathlist` variable as that may cause problems when matching (the main culprit being `"."`)